# Як правильно перекласти з російської мови "Ведущий - ведомый"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно перекласти з російської мови "Ведущий - ведомый"?
З англійської "master - slave"

[Приклад речення, яке потрібно перекласти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

> *В сетях, работающих по принципу *ведущий—ведомый* (Master—Slave), только *ведущее* устройство может инициировать передачу данных и определяет порядок доступа к сети"

[Lingvoforum](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=253.75)

> *В залежності від контектсту:
>   *ведущий*
>    - (здатн. акт.) :
>   1) водiйний, відничий, проводiйний, провідничий, головний; 
>   2) тяговий, рушiйний; 
>    - (в акт.дії) :
>   1) що ведe, що провoдить, що провaдить; 
>   2) що тягне, що рyхає; 
>    - (акт.суб'єкт дії) :
>   1) водiй, віднuк, проводiй, провіднuк, провaдник; 
>   2) тяжiй, рушiй.
>
> *ведомый*
>    - (здатн. пас.) :
>   1) відний, провідний, провадний; 
>   2) тяжний, рухoмий; 
>    - (у пас. дії) :
>   1) вeдений, провoдяний, провaджений; 
>   2) тягнений, рyханий; 
>    - (пас. об'єкт дії) :
>   1) вeдень, тяжень, рyханець.
>
> Якщо, наприклад, мова йде про ведущий вал - ведомый вал, то беремо пару тяговий вал - тяжний вал

Якщо подивитися на варіанти, то жоден в повній мірі не розкриває зміст цих понять.
Буду рада дискусії)

Comment: Ну, в [цьому коментарі](//lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=253.75#msg47584) за Вашим же посиланням добре пояснили, що єдиного перекладу немає, в різних контекстах краще підходять різні варіанти. І навіть навели варіанти. Мені загалом вони подобаються, хіба що я не розумію, чому Ґонта слово _провідний_ відніс до «ведомого», по-моєму, це радше «ведущий» (хоча, можливо, в якихось контекстах по-іншому).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь, але мені здається, що ці варіанти все-рівно не відповідають потрібному змісту (master - slave)

Comment: А приклад контексту застосування можна?

Comment: В сетях, работающих по принципу ведущий—ведомые (Master—Slave), только ведущее устройство может инициировать передачу данных и определяет порядок доступа к сети.

Для ведучого ще нормально, ну от ведомый - ведений, провадний - якось не дуже "звучить"(

Comment: [Ось варіанти для _slave_ зі «Англійсько-українського словника з математики та інформатики» Є. Мейнаровича та М. Кратка (2010)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=slave&dicts=2&highlight=on&filter_lines=on).

Comment: Ще є [«Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» О. Кочерги та Є. Мейнаровича (2010)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=slave&dicts=4&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), але там майже те саме.

Comment: Взагалі, питання дуже гарне (за змістом) — тут є над чим розмислити. На жаль, у мене немає зараз часу цим займатися, збирати різні варіанти і т. ін. (До речі, bytebuster правий, що сам текст питання варто було б переформулювати; питання мають бути написані так, щоб вони могли допомогти не лише його автору, а й іншим зацікавленим читачам; типу, докладне пояснення, що саме треба, щоби легко було знайти пошуком і т. ін.)

Answer (score 3):

Переклад залежатиме від контексту, заглянемо на [ОнлайнКорректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/):

> Вживання дієприкметників активного стану з -уч-, -юч- не рекомендовано
>   нормами сучасної української мови. Замініть кальку ведучий на один з
>   варіантів:
>
> **провідний**, **ключовий** — авторитетний, досвідчений;
>
> **головний**, **чільний** — який указує дорогу, визначає напрямок руху;
>
> **тяговий**, **рушійний**  — про механізм, пристрій.

Наприклад, не ведуче колесо, а тягове колесо.

АЛЕ:

**ведучий програми**, концерту — про особу. Втім, словники пропонують заміну залежно від контексту: відник, провідник, модератор, чільник, голова.

А от "ведомый" джерела дають як "[ведений](http://sum.in.ua/s/vedenyj)", наприклад:

> Ведомый мост – ведений міст ([джерело](https://www.autocentre.ua/ua/avtopravo/avtoshkola/slovar-avtomobilnykh-terminov-govorimo-ukrayinskoyu-292116.html))
>
> Скотта: «Набираясь опыта и добиваясь успеха, будучи **ведомым** Духом, вы
>   почувствуете, что ваше доверие получаемым свыше внушениям станет
>   надежнее, чем зависимость от того, что вы видите или слышите»11.
>
> Скотт: “Якщо ви набудете досвіду й успіху в тому, щоб бути **веденими**
>   Духом, ваша довіра до вражень, які ви відчуваєте, може стати набагато
>   певнішою за вашу довіру до того, що ви бачите або чуєте”11. ([джерело](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9))

Також додам ще варіанти із [Російсько-українського словника](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53394/121737.html):

> I. 1) **відомий, знаний**;
>
> 2) (подведомственный) **підвідомний** (в СУМі **[підвідомчий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidvidomchyj)**), **підурядний**, що перебуває під чиїмсь урядом,присудом.
>
> II. **проваджений**.

Переклад пари із запитання, гадаю, може бути таким: "В мережах, які працюють за принципом **Головний** - **Підвідомчий** (або ж керований, ну але це особисто моя думка), лише **головний пристрій** може ініціювати передачу данних та визначити порядок доступу до мережі".

Якщо ж говоримо, наприклад, про колеса -**"тягове колесо" та "ведене колесо"**.

Comment: З вашої відповіді не зовсім зрозуміло, як ви пропонуєте перекласти цю пару слів. Не кожне слово окремо, а саме пару слів. Доповните трішки відповідь?

Answer (score 0):

Якщо чесно — всі варіанти звучать жахливо.

Власне, я шукав переклад термінів «ведущий»/«ведомый» вал коробки перемикання передач, мені здається, тут треба уникати пастки прямого калькування з російської, наприклад, англійською ці деталі підписують як input shaft, output shaft — **вхідний вал, вихідний вал**, як на мене, звучить цілком адекватно.

Те ж саме щодо master/slave, мені здається, не дуже правильно перекладати як «ведущий»/«ведомый», скоріше «главный»/«подчиненный», відповідно українською — головний/підпорядкований — **головний пристрій, підпорядкований пристрій**.

Не треба видумувати ці жахливі слова — тяжний, відний, руханий… Це просто якісь мертві слова, які ніхто не буде ні розуміти, ні вживати.

Comment: Мені дуже подобається думка, що треба не напряму калькувати, а підбирати в залежності від контексту (наприклад, вхідний/вихідний вал і головний/підпорядкований пристрій). Але раджу прибрати різку критику інших варіантів, бо, я боюся, за неї можуть понаставляюти «мінусів» (просто тут прийнято у відповідях більше пропонувати, ніж критикувати; тим більше коли критика суб'єктивна (типу «звучать жахливо / мертві слова»), а не базована на якихось джерелах (типу, «ось частоти вживання цих слів у літературі — ми бачимо, що оце слово вживають усе рідше й рідше, а оте слово взагалі ніколи не вживали»)).

Comment: Чому *питний* розуміють, а *тяжний* не зрозуміють?

Comment: _Питний_ - це той що можна пити - питна вода, питний спирт. Тоді _тяжний_ по аналогії - той що можна тягти?  Я звичайно ж зустрічав слово _питний_ у житті - як в розмові так і в тексті, слово _тяжний_ - ніколи. Я не розумію значення цього слова.

Comment: Ви щойно правильно описали значення цього слова. Чим же воно гірше ніж *їстівний* чи *невгамовний*? Творення нових слів важливе для мови. Якщо маєте час, і вам цікаво про подібний словотвір, то [ось тут](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162) в першому пункті це описано.

Comment: @Yola дякую, прочитав, цікаво. Чим гірше? Та нічим, хіба що поширеністю, просто я не можу уявити жодного прикладу використання цього слова.  Я легко можу придумати приклади словами _їстівний_, _невгамовний_, _нехтовний_ чи _інтегровний_ і ситуації, в яких ці слова _використовні_. Наведіть, будь ласка приклади з словом _тяжний_, якщо не важко.

Answer (score -1):

Ці терміни походять з авіації? Я точно не скажу, як в цій області знань це правильно перекласти, але можу запропонувати такі варіанти:

1. **Головний - ведений**,
2. **Головний - підрядний**,
3. **Головний - другорядний**,
4. **Головний - рядовий**.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].